# Is using "deal" as a verb in a sense of "make a deal" proper English? (Major spoilers ahead from the movie "se7en"!)

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, non-standard-english

This context comes from the movie "**se7en**" by David Fincher. **Spoilers coming in 3,2,1**. The conversation takes place after a criminal eluding capture by a pair of detectives Mills and Somerset throughout of the extent of the entire movie, and who committed at least 5 murders, turns himself in at a police precinct, and after he demanded to speak to his lawyer and was granted that request. The conversation takes place after the defense attorney conferred with the criminal in an interrogation room, between him, two detectives, a police captain, and some cop I really can't really place in the movie prior to that scene.

```
          *lawyer:
```

- My client says there're 2 more bodies.
  Two more victims hidden away.
  He will take Detectives Mills and
  Somerset to these bodies, only them...
  and only at 6 o'clock today.

  ```
          Mills:
  ```
- Why us?
  lawyer:
  He says he admires you.
  Somerset:
  It's part of the game.

  ```
         lawyer:
  ```
- If they don't accept this offer,
  these bodies will never be found.

  ```
        some cop:
  ```
- Frankly, I'm inclined to let them rot.

  ```
        Miles:
  ```
- We've got him.
  Downstairs, locked up. Done deal.
  He'll get his free room and board,cable TV.
  My wife doesn't even have cable.
  Why are we discussing this?
  No. Something stinks. And this one--
  You. In your $3,000 suit...
  and that smug smile on your face.
  **Dealing for that piece of shit**.
  I don't like it.

  ```
       lawyer:
  ```
- The law requires me to serve...
  my clients and their interests
  as best I can.*

**There is no definition for "deal" as a verb in any dictionary I know of which contains a sense of "make a deal" but it seems to me that this is what he says based on the context**

Comment: Can you correct the formatting of this post?  It's really messed up and hard to read.

Comment: Are you interpreting _deal_ as "**conclude** a deal", or "**negotiate for** a deal"? "Make a deal" could mean either.

Comment: @Colin Fine: based on the context I assumed that he used it in the sense of "negotiate for"(I tough "dealing for" might mean "to make a deal for") but of course if it's not, I would like to know what it means anyway:)

Comment: @stangdon: I corrected the formatting. I hope it's better now.

Comment: I would have thought that **dealing with** means **interacting with** or **working with** in this context. In other words "Having this piece of shit as a client"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deal):

> **deal**
>
> *intransitive verb*
> ...
>
> 4b: to engage in bargaining : trade

They also have a thesaurus entry for ["dealing (for) verb"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/dealing%20%28for%29), which explains that it's used in the sense of "haggling (for)"